# Calculate standard deviation and average for an item from the dataset in excel

Tags: excel, standard-deviation

I wanted to calculate standard deviation and average of sales of three employees across months in excel . Is there a formula which can give be that based on the selected name of the employee ? I want it to be a repeatable and scalable formula for 100 employees .
Also, I don't want to use pivot functionality here as I want to use std dev and average in a pivot field . 
**Input** 
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGSps.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbZHD.jpg)

Comment: This is just a hint : have you looked at AVERAGEIFS() ?

Comment: Average is still workable but I'm stuck at standard deviation

Comment: Why is pivottable not viable and what does "Also, I don't want to use pivot functionality here as I want to use std dev and average in a pivot field" mean?

Comment: I want to use average and std deviation as a pivot filed that I can use to calculate Coeff. of variation as a calculated field in pivot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
=STDEV(IF($A$2:$A$19=G4,$C$2:$C$19))
```

And

```
=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$19=G4,$C$2:$C$19))
```

Enter using [Ctrl + Shift + Enter](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) as array formula and drag down for the number of names.

Names are in G4:G6. Formula in H and I between rows 4 and 6. Data in A2:C19.

Data as follows:

[image: Data]

Wrap in IFERROR if you wish to suppress any errors e.g.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$19=G4,$C$2:$C$19)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks @Qharr  !  This should work as a charm . However I'm getting divisionbyzero error - could it be because some of the sales are 0 ?

Comment: However I'm getting divisionbyzero error - could it be because some of the sales are 0 ?

Comment: One moment caller!

Comment: Even if I put all the sales for one person to zero this still works. I would need to see what data set is actually causing the problem.

Comment: You can wrap in IFERROR to hide the error message e.g. =IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$19=G4,$C$2:$C$19)),"")

Comment: I up voted - thanks! let me see if I can uplaod/share the data here